# JUnit test of a java asyncron method

Tags: java, junit

Today I had to write a method which get a String as a parameter, make a new thread and write it out to the consol after 5 seconds waiting, so something like this:

```
public void exampleMethod(final String str){

    Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable(){    
        public void run(){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                System.out.println(str);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {                      
                //handling of the exception
            }                   
        }
    };

    Thread thread = new Thread(myRunnable);
    thread.start();
    //some other things to do 
}
```

My question is: How can I test and what should I test in here with JUnit?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing complex in this method. You are only using standard API-methods: `Thread.sleep`, `System.out.println`, ...

The parameter is just printed, you don't modify it nor use it for a calculation or another method.

There are no side-effects to your own written code, just to the STL.

And there is no result of the method, which you could test.

In my opinion it is not necessary and not simply possible to test it.
The only thing you could test (and even that wouldn't be trivial), is, if after an amount of time the `String` is printed.

Answer (score 0):

> [...] JUnit finishes execution while the thread is still alive. There could have been problems down the line, toward the end of that thread's execution, but your test would never reflect it.
>   The problem lies in JUnit's TestRunner. It isn't designed to look for Runnable instances and wait around to report on their activities. It fires them off and forgets about them. For this reason, multithreaded unit tests in JUnit have been nearly impossible to write and maintain.

Well, the source - [this article](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2003/08/06/multithreadedTests.html) - is from 2003 and there's no guarantee that this hasn't been fixed yet, but you may try it out yourself.

My suggestion would be:
Run your code and measure the time it takes. Then add some 1000 milliseconds and but a `Thread.sleep(executionTime+1000);` after you started you asynchronous task. Not that elegant, but should work in practice. If you want more elegance here (and waste less time), you may want to look for framework that provide a solution.
...Or if you start your `Thread` directly in the test, you may also use `Thread.join` to wait, but you will have cases, where you aren't able to do that.

**EDIT:**
Also check [this article](http://eyalsch.wordpress.com/2010/07/13/multithreaded-tests/), which could provide a solution to pipe those errors to the main thread:

```
public class AsynchTester{
    private Thread thread;
    private volatile Error error;
    private volatile RuntimeException runtimeExc;

    public AsynchTester(final Runnable runnable) {
        thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    runnable.run();
                } catch (Error e) {
                    error = e;
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    runtimeExc = e;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void start() {
        thread.start();
    }

    public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        thread.join();
        if (error != null)
            throw error;
        if (runtimeExc != null)
            throw runtimeExc;
    }
}
```

Use it like that:

```
@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    AsynchTester tester = new AsynchTester(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           //async code
        }
    });
    tester.start(); 
    tester.test();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are trying to test an interaction instead of a simple returned result or a state change. However, that does not mean it can't be done.

The standard out `PrintStream` can be replaced with [`System.setOut()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut-java.io.PrintStream-). You can inject your own mock implementation that would allow you verify that the `String` was written to the stream. You just have to be careful, since this changes the global state, it might effect other code or tests that rely on standard output. At a minimum, you will have to put back the original stream. But things might get more complicated if tests are running in parallel.

This takes us to the next issue, the sleep. There isn't a strong guarantee to how long a sleep will block. This means your test would have to provide some buffer to ensure that the thread had time to write the `String` before checking the state of the mock stream. You don't want your test to be flaky because of some execution timing jitter. So you would have to decide what buffer you would consider acceptable.

---

An alternative approach would be to change the implementation of the code so that it is easier to test.

The simplest way to do this is to remove all the static dependencies. Instead of explicitly referencing `System.out`, the class could be initialized with with an `PrintStream` to write to. Additionally, you could define an interface that would wrap `Thread.sleep()`. For testing purposes, you can initialize the class with the mock stream and no-op implementation of the sleep interface. However, you may still have some timing issues as you need the newly created thread to execute before continuing the test.

---

The other thing you can do is take a step back and decide how much you care about this code being tested. There are only 4 interesting lines of code in this sample and none of them are complicated. Having a code review could be sufficient to ensure there are no bugs.

However, if the business logic is more complicate than writing to standard out, you might decided that testing that is important. The good news is that scheduling a task in an executor is straight forward and that is the part that is making the testing hard. You could make an abstraction that encompasses the scheduling of the task in a background thread. Then provide yourself with more direct access to the business logic in order to test that.

Answer (score 0):

I have often solved that, by providing a ResultTarget which implements an interface IResultTarget to the thread,
In productive code the result will be a list that contains the calculation result. (or null)

In your unit test the ResultTarget is the unit test class itself, which then easily can check the received result.

```
public Interface IResultTarget {
  List getResult();
}

public void ThreadTest extends TestCase implements IResultTarget {

 List result;

 public List getResult(
   return this.result;
 }

 public void testThread() {
   MyRunnable myRunnable= new MyRunnable ();
   myRunnable.setResultTarget(this);
   Thread thread = new Thread(myRunnable);
   thread .start();

   Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);
   // expecting one element as result of the work of myRunnable.
   assertEquals(1, result.size());
 }
}
```